# Postgres - Deleting duplicates rows to ensure unique index works

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, postgresql-9.5

I have a table structured as:

```
id | foodid | ingredientid
```

I want to create a unique index as follows:

```
create unique index foodingredient_foodid_ingredientid_uindex
    on foodingredient (foodid, ingredientid);
```

The problem is the table contains lots of duplicate foodid and ingredientid entries. These are unnecessary and I want to delete them.

If I run:

```
select count(*)
from foodingredient
group by foodid, ingredientid
having count(*) > 1
order by count desc
```

This returns half a million rows. So fixing these manually isn't an option.

So what I'm wanting to do is delete all duplicates whilst keeping the original.

I.e.

```
id | foodid | ingredientid
1  | 144    | 531
2  | 144    | 531
3  | 144    | 531
4  | 144    | 531
```

Becomes:

```
id | foodid | ingredientid
1  | 144    | 531
```

Is there a way to do this with a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with exists:

```
delete from foodingredient t
where exists (
  select 1 from foodingredient
  where foodid = t.foodid and ingredientid = t.ingredientid and id < t.id
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=10dddd998e49e3063a0dd2232072a4da).

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM foodingredient a
USING foodingredient b
WHERE a.id > b.id
    AND a.foodid = b.foodid 
    AND a.ingredientid = b.ingredientid;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also just select only rows that are distinct and use them to create new table.

Plain select just to see what is going on.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (foodid, ingredientid) id, foodid, ingredientid
   FROM foodingredient LIMIT 100
```

Create new table from SELECT above.

```
CREATE TABLE foodingredient_uniq AS select * FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON(foodid, ingredientid) id, foodid, ingredientid
  FROM foodingredient
)
```

If you like to have new table ordered by id then also add ORDER BY

```
CREATE TABLE foodingredient_uniq AS select * FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON(foodid, ingredientid) id, foodid, ingredientid
  FROM foodingredient
) t1 ORDER BY t1.id
```

Then just drop old table and rename foodingredient_uniq to foodingredient. It is much faster than self join solutions above for really huge tables. 24 hour vs 20 minutes on my own use case with 200M row table and ~30% unique rows.